# If a series is infinite at some early point can it converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose I have a series defined :
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}100/ln(n)$.

My intuition tells me it diverges because at n equals 1 the term is infinite (according to the partial sum definition), however my teacher taught me this:

If N is a positive integer, then the series
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ 
and 
$\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}a_n$
both converge or both diverge.

Which one is correct?

Comment: $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{100}{\log n}$ is not the *definition* of a series since $\frac{100}{\log 1}$ has no meaning / is not a number.

Comment: so to be a series, the term has to be in proper form ?

Comment: In order that something can be considered *a definition*, its parts have to make sense, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Suppose I have a series defined :
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}100/ln(n)$

This doesn't make sense since $\ln 1 = 0$ so $\tfrac{100}{\ln n}$ isn't defined at $n=1$.

> if N is a positive integer, then the series
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}an$ 
>   and 
>   $\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}an$
>   both converge or both diverge.

Try to understand what this means: convergence is only determined by *"the tail"* of the series, not by a **finite** number of terms in the beginning since the sum of a finite number of numbers, is finite as well.

Comment: thanks a lot, for the answer..

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is on the very first line.
You have not defined a series.
In a legitimate series every term is a real number — or complex or in some other fixed space.
At $n=1$ you don't have a well defined number.
In a series every term is finite.

Answer (score 0):

For the first series, you should write

$$\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac{100}{\ln(n)}$$

Yes, If the series are well defined,

they will have the same nature since $$\sum_{n=1}^ma_n=\sum_{n=1}^Na_n+\sum_{n=N+1}^ma_n$$

When $m\to+\infty$, both sides will converge or both diverge.

$\sum_{n=1}^Na_n$ do not depend on $m$.